# Uh oh Looks like something went wrong. Please try again later. Yahoo Passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, yahoo

I'm build autheticate using passport yahoo, this is my configuration

```
yahoo : {
      clientID: "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYy",
      clientSecret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      callbackURL: "http://black.jack.co/auth/yahoo/callback"
    }
```

and this is my configuration on yahoo developer
Aplication Name: autheticate yahoo
Home page URL:  http://black.jack.co
Callback Domain : http://jack.co

When I tried to login, yahoo callback give an error 
**Uh oh
Looks like something went wrong.
Please try again later.** How to fix this?

Comment: You should probably hide your secrets... Hope that's not your real configuration.

Comment: Do you find any solution regarding this

Answer (score 0):

Please look after your URL

just double clicking and trying to change clientid will not help due to -- present in the url below

https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?
client_id=dj0yJmk9ak5IZ2x5WmNsaHp6JmQ9WVdrOVNqQkJUMnRYTjJrbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1hYQ-- //this over here is ok -- might be extra for your client id

&redirect_uri=oob

&response_type=code

&language=en-us

double click will generate

https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?

client_id=[YOURIDAND]--

&redirect_uri=oob

&response_type=code

&language=en-us

If this wont help please delete app and recreate

Your client id will not always have -- at the end

I made a stupid mistake and spend extra time to resolve the issue hope it helps